# how to get the package infomation of a jar file

Tags: java

I want to get the the package infomation of a jar file with java code.That is,get all package names,list the classes in each package.

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with java, by opening the jar file, and examining the files inside.
Use the java api class JarFile. I use that method in the static constructor for this class, in a project:
https://sourceforge.net/p/flamethyst/code/64/tree/trunk/source/com/paxinum/flamethyst/function/VariationFactory.java

Answer (score 0):

check the below link , it will help you [class and packeage details](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0513.html)